# Javascript overhead of repeated allocation

Tags: javascript, optimization, object, allocation

I'm making a pretty simple game just for fun/practice but I still want to code it well regardless of how simple it is now, in case I want to come back to it and just to learn

So, in that context, my question is:

How much overhead is involved in object allocation? And how well does the interpreter already optimize this? I'm going to be repeatedly checking object grid positions, and if they are still in the same grid square, then no updating the grid array

```
if (obj.gridPos==obj.getCurrentGridPos()){
    //etc
}
```

But, should I keep an outer "work" point object that the `getCurrentGridPos()` changes each time or should it return a new point object each time?

Basically, even if the overhead of creating a point object isnt all that much to matter in this scenario, which is faster?

EDIT:
this? which will get called every object each frame

```
function getGridPos(x,y){
  return new Point(Math.ceil(x/25),Math.ceil(y/25));
}
```

or

```
//outside the frame by frame update function looping through every object each frame
tempPoint= new Point()

//and each object each frame calls this, passing in tempPoint and checking that value
function makeGridPos(pt,x,y){
  pt.x = Math.ceil(x/25);
  pt.y = Math.ceil(y/25);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between your two code examples that you have now added, I know of no case where the first would be more efficient than the second.  So, if you're trying to optimize for performance or memory use, then re-using an existing object will likely be more efficient than creating a new object each time you call the function.

Note: since JS refers to object by reference, you will have to make sure that your code is not elsewhere hanging on to that object and expecting it to keep its value.

---

Prior answer:

In all programming (regardless of how good the optimizer is), you are always better caching a result calculated as a result of accessing several member variables that you are using over and over again in the same function rather than recalling the function that calculates it over and over.

So, if you are calling `obj.getCurrentGridPos()` more than once and conditions have not changed such that it might return a different result, then you should cache it's value locally (in any language).  This is just good programming.

```
var currentPos = obj.getCurrentGridPos();
```

And, then use that locally cached value:

```
if (obj.gridPos == currentPos) {
```

The interpreter may not be able to do this type of optimization for you because it may not be able to tell whether other operations might cause `obj.getCurrentGridPos()` to return something different from one call to another, but you the programmer can know that.

One other thing.  If `obj.getCurrentGridPos()` returns an actual object, then you probably don't want to be using `==` or `===` to compare objects.  That compares ONLY to see if they are literally the same object - it does not compare to see if the two objects have the same properties.

Comment: the issue is that I'm calling on this on multiple objects each frame, so even if every object hasnt moved, I'm still creating lots of currentPos objects each time, so is it better to just make it change an inputted point rather than return a new point, so only one point is being used by all objects to check grid position and so a new Point() is being called in the return statement of each getCurrentGridPos() call

Comment: @user864572 - I can't tell without seeing more of the code.  Fewer objects is generally better than more objects if you are trying to optimize for performance and memory use.

Comment: The first paragraph is way too general. There are enough situations where caching everything will adversely affect performance. For one memory accesses are extremely expensive these days and second memory (and caches) are a finite resource.

Comment: @Voo - I'm not arguing that there aren't extreme cases where caching a computed value might lead to too many overall cached values, but that isn't what we're talking about here.  I'm talking about caching the result of ONE function call that is called multiple times in the same function.  Find me any case where caching that value results in more memory accesses than calling the function repeatedly - it simply doesn't.  The function itself is doing multiple memory accesses on the object to calculate it's answer.  That is NEVER fewer memory accesses than accessing a single cached result.

Comment: @jfriend00 As I said, too general. If you limit it to that case, yes it's generally a good idea, although a good compiler in a sensible language will do it anyhow - sadly generally necessary in JS. But since I like challenges, actually even in this special case it's not imppssible: Recomputing eg the sqrt of some value takes about 5 cycles with SSE (rsqrt with SB); assuming the compiler can't keep the additional variable in a register, the memory access will take between 8 (l2), 30 (l3) and several hundred (RAM) cycles.

Comment: @Voo - OK, I added words to limit it to that case.  It turns out this isn't what the OP is doing anyway.  If they would just include their actual code, we could provide so much better targeted answers.

Comment: @user864572 - I added a new part to my answer (at the beginning) to respond to your code examples (thanks for adding them).

Comment: You said reusing an object would be more efficient than making a new one each time but then said the second one was not better? The first one is making a new point to return each time while the second is reusing the same tempPoint global (well, outer scope/JS global)

Comment: @user864572 - Typo in my answer (that I have now corrected).  The second one (reusing the object) is better.

Answer (score 1):

This question is *VERY* difficult to answer because of all the different javascript engine's out there. The "big 4" of browsers all have their own javascript engine/interpreter and each one is going to do their allocation, caching, GCing, etc.. differently.

The Chrome (and Safari) dev tools have a profiling tab where you can profile memory allocation, timings, etc of your code. This will be a place to start (at least for Chrome and Safari)

I'm not certain if IE or Firefox offer such tools, but I wouldn't be surprised if some third party tools exist for these browsers for testing such things...

Also, for reference -

- Chrome uses the V8 javascript engine
- I.E uses the Triton (I think it's still called that?) javascript engine
- Firefox I believe uses Spidermonkey
- Safari I'm not sure about, but think it's using the one that's part of WebKit.

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that garbage collection stops execution on most JS engines. If you're going to be making many objects per iteration through your game loop and letting them go out of scope that will cause slowdown when the garbage collector takes over.

For this kind of situation you might consider making a singleton to pool your objects with a method to recycle them for reuse by deleting all of their properties, resetting their `__proto__` to `Object.prototype`, and storing them in an array. You can then request recycled objects from the pool as needed, only increasing the pool size when it runs dry.

Comment: So in this example, keeping an outer temp point would in fact solve that issue? Thanks, I figured garbage collection was a performance hit but I didnt know it was that significant

Comment: If I understand you, obj.gridPos is a point object like {x:50,y:50} and you're checking to see whether or not obj.getCurrentGridPos() returns a reference to the very same object?

Comment: You might want to just keep a single point per object. When an object moves, push the whole thing to a queue. Every cycle of your animation loop, unshift objects off the queue until it's empty or you run out of time, updating their displayed positions as you go. I don't know if you're making a real-time game or you need to animate between these positions, so I don't know how much information you need per update. But if you're just checking if it's in the same place, and if not draw it somewhere else on a grid, this might work--you'd only ever need to know it's current location.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to set one `current position` object and check against itself as you're literally going to use more memory  if you create a new object every time you call `getCurrentGridPos()`.

There may be a better place for the `is this a new position` check since you should only do that check once per iteration.

It seems optimal to set the `currentGridPos` using a [RequestAnimationFrame](https://gist.github.com/1579671) and check against its current `x y z` positions before updating it so you can then trigger a `changedPosition` type event.

```
var currentPos = {
    x:0,
    y:0,
    z:0
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(function(newPos){
    if (currentPos.x != currentPos.x || currentPos.y != currentPos.y || currentPos.z != newPos.z) {
        $.publish("positionChanged"); // tinypubsub https://gist.github.com/661855
    }
})
```

So, just to be clear, yes I think you should keep an outer "work" point object that updates every iteration... and while it's updating you could check to see if its position has changed - this would be a more intentful way to organize the logic and ensure you don't call `getCurrentPos` more than once per iteration.